# WebdriverIO - How do I set the custom repository for drivers?

Tags: webdriver-io

I need to use custom npm repository for drivers in WebdriverIO. It's configured in .npmrc file and all the package.json dependencies are taken from there. But the WebdriverIO is trying to download drivers (i.e. chromedriver) from the Internet (which is restricted in the company).

The latest version of WebdriverIO is used.

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to configure the source for drivers somehow (couldn't find it in docs) or I have to find more complex workarounds. Please share your experience with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also asked this in their GitHub and **christian-bromann** answered there's no such an option. It's only possible to use the binary driver path locally:

```
capabilities: [{
  browserName: 'chrome',
  'wdio:chromedriverOptions': { binary: '/path/to/binary' }
}]
```